# Drop down menu second link disappears on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm very new to CSS but can't seem to find a fix for my issue in any of the threads I've found, though it seems a common problem.

Basically I have a drop down menu and when i hover over it, the drop downs display fine, however when i mouse over past the first drop down link, it disappears. So I'm assuming I have a problem with my second drop down link, but no idea how to fix it.

Here's a screencast of what is happening:
[Drop Down Broken Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZZRP.gif)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #fcc800;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21.5px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #000000;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18.5px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000000;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 22.5px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 33px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 16.5px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #000000;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21.5px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15.5px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000000;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 22.5px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 22.5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #e3b400;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21.5px;
  right: 18.5px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #000000;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 14px;
  right: 12px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18.5px;
  right: 21.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000000;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 11px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}

.header-top{
  height: 72px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

  .sub-menu {
z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu" class="align-center">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">FORD</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/ford-courier-seat-covers">COURIER</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Ford+Ranger">RANGER</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">GREAT WALL</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/great-wall-0311-current">V200/V240</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/great-wall-x200x240-series">X200/X240</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">HOLDEN</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Holden+Colorado">COLORADO</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Holden+Rodeo">RODEO</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">ISUZU</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Isuzu+DMAX">DMAX</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/isuzu-mu-x-0614-current">MUX</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">LAND ROVER</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Land+Rover+Defender">DEFENDER</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">MAZDA</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/mazda-bravo-0699-1106-series-1-2-series-2-facelift">BRAVO</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Mazda+BT50">BT50</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">MITSUBISHI</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Mitsubishi+Triton">TRITON</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">NISSAN</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Nissan+Navara+D22">NAVARA D22</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/nissan-navara-d23-0315-current-np300-dxrxstst-x">NAVARA D23</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Nissan+Navara+D40">NAVARA D40</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Nissan+Patrol+Wagon">PATROL WAGON</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Nissan+Patrol+Utilities">PATROL UTILITIES</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/nissan-pathfinder-0805-current-r51-stst-l">PATHFINDER</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/paratus">PARATUS</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/stratos">STRATOS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">TOYOTA</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+Hilux">HILUX</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/toyota-lc200-1008-current-gxgxl">LC200</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+LC100+Series">LC100</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+LC80+Series">LC80</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+LC79+Series">LC79</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+LC78+Series">LC78</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/toyota-lc76-0307-0812-wagonworkmategxl">LC76</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+LC75+Series">LC75</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+LC70+Series">LC70</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/?category=Toyota+Prado">LC PRADO</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">VOLKSWAGEN</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/volkswagen-amarok-0511-current-amaroktrendlinehighlineultimate">AMAROK</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/universal">UNIVERSAL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be awesome, been trying to fix it for a while now with no luck!

Comment: which browser are you  using..can't replicate that in chrome!

Comment: Chrome and Firefox on Mac are rendering the code snippet ok. Usually, this happens if there's a gap between the "show the submenu" element and its child menu. Check it out in your browser tools to see where one element ends and the next begins.

Comment: I'm using chrome. It's strange it seems to work when uploaded like that, but on the actual website it keeps disappearing. The link to the page with the menu is https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/

Comment: @NishanthMatha any other ideas at all? Still having the same problem

Comment: I checked your site (the link given) in chrome and still couldn't replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have created the codepen URL - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KMpLqz and looks fine

Try increasing css transition time

```
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
      -o-transition: all .25s ease;
      transition: all .25s ease;
```

Comment: I have tried increasing this and still doesn't seem to be working properly for me.